# Include Different letter tempates under ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am wanting to see if there is a way to bring in letter templates that have different text content on them inside my ng-repeat which only brings in the template title from my server. I want to see if I can get the content in without putting it along the other data on the server. Any suggestions?

Here is my controller where I am currently bringing in 1 template but that template is being repeated when I dont want it to be:

```js
app.controller('letterTemplatesCtrl', function($scope, letterTemplatesSrv) {

    $scope.getAllTemplates = letterTemplatesSrv.getAllTemplates().then(function(response) {
        $scope.templates = response.data;
    });

    //Changes tempalte border to red when select button is clicked
    $scope.activeTemplate = function(index) {
        $scope.isSelected = index;
    };

    // Truncated letter template content
    $scope.longText1 = "Dear (name), Ho Ho Ho! Merry Christmas! The Elves and I are busy making presents for all of the good boys and girls around the world. You have been such a good (boy/girl) this year, so I wanted to take a minute to write you a letter. I’ve made my Naughty and Nice list, and I’ve checked it twice. You are on my Nice List! I am so happy that you have been such a good (boy/girl) this year.I heard from my secret messenger that you want (What do they want for Christmas?) for Christmas this year. Because you have been so good, the Elves and I have prepared a special present for you to open on Christmas Morning. Can you do me a favor? I want you to try really hard to (insert something that the child needs to work on). If you can do that for me, then I will be very happy and might bring you an extra treat on Christmas Morning. By the time I get to your house in (location), I am going to be very hungry. Would you leave some cookies and milk out for me? Chocolate Chip cookies are my favorite, but I love all kinds of cookies! Well I need to get back to my workshop and help the Elves. Keep up the good work (Name) and have a Very Merry Christmas! Ho Ho Ho, Santa Claus";

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-padding layout-margin layout-align="center center">
    <div flex ng-repeat="template in templates">
        <div class="template-chooser" ng-class="{'selected-template':isSelected === $index}">
            <span class="template-title">{{template.template_name}}</span>
            <p class="template-content" ng-text-truncate="longText1" ng-tt-chars-threshold="40"></p>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary template-chooser-btn" ng-click="addProductToCart(product); activeTemplate($index)">Select</md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is in `templates`?  right now, you are iterating over the `templates`, and for each `template` you are outputting `template.template_name` along with something called `longText1` that has nothing to do with the `template`.  I suspect you *might* want to output something like `template.template_text` instead.....

Comment: @Claies templates is on my server which just has an id and a name for each template so I can track it as it is adding to a shopping cart(to come later). Each template will have a letter in it which will have different text/style and I didn't want to put it on the server as another column as I would not be able to style that as to my knowledge. I wanted to include longtext1 in there in a manner so I could change the text with something like longtext2, longtext3, etc.

Comment: This still isn't exactly making sense.  what does "put it on the server as another column" mean, exactly?  and how were you planning on changing `longText1` to `longtext2`, `longtext3`, etc.?

Comment: @Claies What I am saying is I can add template_text to my server and add the string that is longText1 and bring it in that way easy enough. Each template(there are 4 in total right now) would have their own string. Doing so wouldn't allow me to style each template how I want and I wanted to know how to do that with the current code I had. I would not change longText1 to anything I was wanting to add them in somehow.

Comment: well you need to have the text stored and be able to read it from *somewhere*;  right now, you are reading `longText1` 4 different times.

Comment: Would it be as simple as putting all of them in an array or?

Comment: isn't `$scope.templates` an array already?

Comment: it really still doesn't make sense what you are asking;  You keep saying that if you add the template text to your server then you can't style it the way you want, but if it's not on the server, then where is it? and the text in the sales screen here isn't the same as the full template file you are selling, anyway, right?